# Dynamic Schema in JPA annotation

Tags: jpa, dynamic, annotations, schema, openjpa

I am Using OpenJPA in My Project with DB2 Database.

Our DBA , does not allowing Synonyms.

we have multiple schema in database (e.g for different schema for DEV & QA )

My Entity class looks like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVSCHEMA.CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
```

When I move the code to QA environment then I need to change the entity to

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QASCHEMA.CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
```

I want to Make one Binary for both environment and do not want to change entity class for  each environment. Is there any possible way ?

FYI- I have multiple schema in each environment also so if there is any default schema option then I can not use that .

Answer (score 1):

You could specify your tables in an orm.xml file and use a different orm.xml file for dev and qa etc. All the other settings (attribute mappings etc.) would be taken from your Java annotations.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your answer .. How do I specify which orm.xml to use at Run time . Do you have any example or link ?

Comment: If the orm.xml file is in the META-INF directory (alongside your persistence.xml file), it should be found automatically. Alternatively, you can specify the name and location of the orm.xml file in the persistence.xml file. You could either edit the orm.xml file when you want different schemata; or you could have multiple orm.xml files with different names and change the entry in the persistence.xml file.